# Can I have TypeScript's compiled JavaScript check types?

Tags: typescript

I've run my code through tsc, and have the following output for a constructor function accepting a single string parameter:

```
function Session(endpoint) {
    var _this = this;
    _super.call(this);
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
```

There's no check that the parameter is defined or that typeof(endpoint) === "string".

Are these checks only made at compile time? I originally had some sanity checks in the constructor to ensure that the value was correct, then deleted them because I assumed tsc would output them. Type declarations will certainly be useful when compiling, but I was hoping for runtime checks as well, and hoping not to have to write all that boilerplate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. Typescript does not have runtime type checks.

A proposition to include this in the language was [declined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573) with a reference to their [design goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals).

Answer (score 1):

Should have known to post a question before my first cup of coffee. Googling "typescript runtime type checks" gave me the answer:

It is apparently [outside of TS' goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573) but there is an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-type-checks) that does it.